# Derivative of horizontal range vs launch angle?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, projectile

So my task was to shoot a marble at different angles with the same initial velocity at an elevation of $0.26$ meters to find the relationship between horizontal range and launch angle.

I was able to simplify the equation for horizontal range to

$$R = \frac{V^2}{2g}\sin(2\theta)\left(1+\sqrt{1+\frac{2gh}{V^2\sin^2\theta}}\right)$$

where:

$v=$ initial velocity

$g=+9.8\,{\rm m}\,{\rm s}^{-2}$ (the negative was already manipulated out in the equation)

$\theta=$ launch angle

$h=$ initial height

Despite all this I CANNOT out figure what ${\rm d}R/{\rm d}\theta$ is supposed to represent.

Answer (score 0):

A derivative tells us the rate of change of one quantity with respect to another. For example d$x$/d$t$ typically represents how fast the position changes as time goes by. You must remember this as velocity. (blatant *Casablanca* pun), $$v=\dfrac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$

If $R$ represents the range from your starting point and $\theta$ represents the launch angle, then $$\dfrac{\mathrm{d}R}{\mathrm{d}\theta}$$
represents how much the range $R$ will change per angular unit as the launch angle $\theta$ changes.

Comment: Yes I know what a derivative is but I am asking what it represents. For instance the derivative of velocity vs time represents accelaration

Comment: There's not a name for that specific derivative that I'm aware of. Maybe the military (artillery) has a name for it, but physics doesn't.